# Convert bytes to bits in python

Tags: python, hex, byte, bit

I am working with Python3.2. I need to take a hex stream as an input and parse it at bit-level. So I used

`bytes.fromhex(input_str)`

to convert the string to actual bytes. Now how do I convert these bytes to bits?

Comment: Bytes are bits, just 8 at a time ;) - The answer depends on what you want to do, please be more specific Also bit-manipulation is mostly done on byte level...

Comment: I want to represent the bytes in the form a bit string so that I can do something like:
field1 = bit_string[0:1]
field2 = bit_string[1:16]
and so on

Comment: Confusing title. Hexadecimals are nothing to do with bytes. Title should be: "Convert hexadecimals to bits in python"

Answer (score 51):

Another way to do this is by using the [`bitstring`](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/) module:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> input_str = '0xff'
>>> c = BitArray(hex=input_str)
>>> c.bin
'0b11111111'
```

And if you need to strip the leading `0b`:

```
>>> c.bin[2:]
'11111111'
```

The `bitstring` module isn't a requirement, as **jcollado**'s answer shows, but it has lots of performant methods for turning input into bits and manipulating them. You might find this handy (or not), for example:

```
>>> c.uint
255
>>> c.invert()
>>> c.bin[2:]
'00000000'
```

etc.

Comment: +1. And for the latest version of bitstring (3.0) you don't need to strip the leading `0b`.

Comment: I have found that, for most cases, bitstring has far worse performance than python builtins like `struct.pack/unpack`

Comment: It will likely help others who come to this question for you to show examples of how those builtins work. If you have time to post an answer, please do.

Comment: In your example, the currnet version of the library won't return a number like '0b1111111' instead it will return without the prefix, so I have been looking into how to pad the number if it representation is less than 8 bit , do you know if it is possible using the bitstring library?

Answer (score 40):

What about something like this?

```
>>> bin(int('ff', base=16))
'0b11111111'
```

This will convert the hexadecimal string you have to an integer and that integer to a string in which each byte is set to 0/1 depending on the bit-value of the integer.

As pointed out by a comment, if you need to get rid of the `0b` prefix, you can do it this way:

```
>>> bin(int('ff', base=16))[2:]
'11111111'
```

... or, if you are using Python 3.9 or newer:

```
>>> bin(int('ff', base=16)).removepreffix('0b')
'11111111'
```

*Note: using `lstrip("0b")` here will lead to `0` integer being converted to an empty string. This is almost always not what you want to do.*

Comment: lstrip('-0b') # remove leading zeros and minus sign

Comment: @ahoffer Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer to let the OP know how to remove the `0b` prefix.

Comment: Note that `lstrip('0b')` will also remove, say, `00bb` since the argument to `lstrip` is a *set* of characters to remove. It'll work fine in this case, but I prefer the `[2:]` solution since it's more explicit.

Comment: @MartinGeisler Yes, `bin` leading zeros are already removed when converting to an integer, but it's worth to note that `lstrip` removes a set of characters, not a prefix.

Comment: **Do not use `lstrip` for this! It will remove ALL leading zeroes, so this will convert 0 integer to an empty string!** The only valid way of doing this without indexing would be using `str.removeprefix()`.

Answer (score 34):

Operations are much faster when you work at the integer level. In particular, converting to a string as suggested here is really slow.

If you want bit 7 and 8 only, use e.g.

```
val = (byte >> 6) & 3
```

(this is: shift the byte 6 bits to the right - dropping them. Then keep only the last two bits `3` is the number with the first two bits set...)

These can easily be translated into simple CPU operations that are super fast.

Answer (score 17):

using python [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
>>> mybyte = bytes.fromhex("1F") # mybyte = b'\x1f'
>>> myhex = mybyte.hex() # myhex = '1f'
>>> myint = int(myhex, 16) # myint = 31
>>> binary_string = "{:08b}".format(myint) # binary_string = '00011111'
>>> print(binary_string)
00011111
```

Byte objects (`b'\x1f'`) have a `.hex()` method, which returns a normal string made up of characters '0' to 'F'. Using this plain string, we then convert it to an `int`, using the `int()` function that takes a string as input, and also that it's a base 16 string (because hex is base 16).

So then we have a normal int, that we want to represent as binary. The next step is we make a new string, using the python string formatting mini-language to apply formatting to that integer so it looks like a binary string.

The `"{:08b}".format(myint)` line is where the magic happens.
The `{:08b}` uses the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) `format_spec`. Specifically it's using the `width` and the `type` parts of the format_spec syntax. The `8` sets `width` to 8, and the `0` before the `8` tells it to pad with zeros (this is how we get the nice 000 padding), and the `b` sets the type to binary.

I prefer this method over the `bin()` built-in function because using a format string gives a lot more flexibility. This fact is even mentioned in the official python docs as part of the `bin()` docs. The docs suggest to [use a format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) if you want more flexibility.

Comment: but this method doesn't let you take a variable number of bytes as input, right?  you need to hard-code how long the final binary string needs to be.

Answer (score 14):

I think simplest would be use `numpy` here. For example you can read a file as bytes and then expand it to bits easily like this:

```
Bytes = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype = "uint8")
Bits = numpy.unpackbits(Bytes)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
input_str = "ABC"
[bin(byte) for byte in bytes(input_str, "utf-8")]
```

Will give:

```
['0b1000001', '0b1000010', '0b1000011']
```

Answer (score 5):

Here how to do it using  `format()`

```
print "bin_signedDate : ", ''.join(format(x, '08b') for x in bytevector)
```

> It is important the **08b** . That means it will be a maximum of 8 leading zeros be appended to complete a byte. If you don't specify this then the format will just have a variable bit length for each converted byte.

Answer (score 4):

To binary:

```
bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8)
```

Comment: You can't convert a byte using bin.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ord` when reading reading bytes:

```
byte_binary = bin(ord(f.read(1))) # Add [2:] to remove the "0b" prefix
```

**Or**

Using `str.format()`:

```
'{:08b}'.format(ord(f.read(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here provide the bits in [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order (`'\x01'` becomes `'00000001'`)

In case you're interested in little-endian order of bits, which is useful in many cases, like common representations of bignums etc -
here's a snippet for that:

```
def bits_little_endian_from_bytes(s):
    return ''.join(bin(ord(x))[2:].rjust(8,'0')[::-1] for x in s)
```

And for the other direction:

```
def bytes_from_bits_little_endian(s):
    return ''.join(chr(int(s[i:i+8][::-1], 2)) for i in range(0, len(s), 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Q: How convert bytes to bits / string of bits?

#### A:

```py
b = ''.join(f'{z:08b}' for z in x)
```

Replace `''.join(.)` with `[.]` for the bit representations.
This answers preserves the size so each byte takes 8 bits and the output is `8 * nbytes` long.

##### Example:

```py
print(''.join(f'{z:08b}' for z in b'DECADE'))
# output: 010001000100010101000011010000010100010001000101
# len(output) is 48 == len('DECADE') * 8
```

Answer (score 0):

One line function to convert bytes (not string) to bit list. There is no endnians issue when source is from a byte reader/writer to another byte reader/writer, only if source and target are bit reader and bit writers.

```
def byte2bin(b):
    return [int(X) for X in "".join(["{:0>8}".format(bin(X)[2:])for X in b])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer when looking for a way to convert an *integer* into a list of bit positions where the bitstring is equal to one. This becomes very similar to this question if you first convert your hex string to an integer like `int('0x453', 16)`.

Now, given an integer - a representation already well-encoded in the hardware, I was very surprised to find out that the string variants of the above solutions using things like `bin` turn out to be faster than numpy based solutions for a single number, and I thought I'd quickly write up the results.

I wrote three variants of the function. First using numpy:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
def bit_positions_numpy(val):
    """
    Given an integer value, return the positions of the on bits.
    """
    bit_length = val.bit_length() + 1
    length = math.ceil(bit_length / 8.0)  # bytelength
    bytestr = val.to_bytes(length, byteorder='big', signed=True)
    arr = np.frombuffer(bytestr, dtype=np.uint8, count=length)
    bit_arr = np.unpackbits(arr, bitorder='big')
    bit_positions = np.where(bit_arr[::-1])[0].tolist()
    return bit_positions
```

Then using string logic:

```
def bit_positions_str(val):
    is_negative = val < 0
    if is_negative:
        bit_length = val.bit_length() + 1
        length = math.ceil(bit_length / 8.0)  # bytelength
        neg_position = (length * 8) - 1
        # special logic for negatives to get twos compliment repr
        max_val = 1 << neg_position
        val_ = max_val + val
    else:
        val_ = val
    binary_string = '{:b}'.format(val_)[::-1]
    bit_positions = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(binary_string)
                     if char == '1']
    if is_negative:
        bit_positions.append(neg_position)
    return bit_positions
```

And finally, I added a third method where I precomputed a lookuptable of the positions for a single byte and expanded that given larger itemsizes.

```py
BYTE_TO_POSITIONS = []
pos_masks = [(s, (1 << s)) for s in range(0, 8)]
for i in range(0, 256):
    positions = [pos  for pos, mask in pos_masks if (mask & i)]
    BYTE_TO_POSITIONS.append(positions)


def bit_positions_lut(val):
    bit_length = val.bit_length() + 1
    length = math.ceil(bit_length / 8.0)  # bytelength
    bytestr = val.to_bytes(length, byteorder='big', signed=True)
    bit_positions = []
    for offset, b in enumerate(bytestr[::-1]):
        pos = BYTE_TO_POSITIONS[b]
        if offset == 0:
            bit_positions.extend(pos)
        else:
            pos_offset = (8 * offset)
            bit_positions.extend([p + pos_offset for p in pos])
    return bit_positions
```

The benchmark code is as follows:

```
def benchmark_bit_conversions():
    # for val in [-0, -1, -3, -4, -9999]:

    test_values = [
        # -1, -2, -3, -4, -8, -32, -290, -9999,
        # 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 32, 290, 9999,
        4324, 1028, 1024, 3000, -100000,
        999999999999,
        -999999999999,
        2 ** 32,
        2 ** 64,
        2 ** 128,
        2 ** 128,
    ]

    for val in test_values:
        r1 = bit_positions_str(val)
        r2 = bit_positions_numpy(val)
        r3 = bit_positions_lut(val)
        print(f'val={val}')
        print(f'r1={r1}')
        print(f'r2={r2}')
        print(f'r3={r3}')
        print('---')
        assert r1 == r2

    import xdev
    xdev.profile_now(bit_positions_numpy)(val)
    xdev.profile_now(bit_positions_str)(val)
    xdev.profile_now(bit_positions_lut)(val)

    import timerit
    ti = timerit.Timerit(10000, bestof=10, verbose=2)
    for timer in ti.reset('str'):
        for val in test_values:
            bit_positions_str(val)

    for timer in ti.reset('numpy'):
        for val in test_values:
            bit_positions_numpy(val)

    for timer in ti.reset('lut'):
        for val in test_values:
            bit_positions_lut(val)

    for timer in ti.reset('raw_bin'):
        for val in test_values:
            bin(val)

    for timer in ti.reset('raw_bytes'):
        for val in test_values:
            val.to_bytes(val.bit_length(), 'big', signed=True)
```

And it clearly shows the str and lookup table implementations are ahead of numpy. I tested this on CPython 3.10 and 3.11.

```
Timed str for: 10000 loops, best of 10
    time per loop: best=20.488 µs, mean=21.438 ± 0.4 µs
Timed numpy for: 10000 loops, best of 10
    time per loop: best=25.754 µs, mean=28.509 ± 5.2 µs
Timed lut for: 10000 loops, best of 10
    time per loop: best=19.420 µs, mean=21.305 ± 3.8 µs
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6+ or newer, you can first convert the hex string to integer using `int(input_str, 16)`. Then use f-strings format to convert the integer to bit string.

```
>>> input_str = b'1a'
>>> f'{int(input_str, 16):b}'
'11010'
```

The width specifier can be used to set the length of the output bit string if the length of the output is less than the specified width:

```
>>> f'{int(input_str, 16):08b}'
'00011010'
```

or

```
>>> len_in_bits = 8
>>> f'{int(input_str, 16):0{len_in_bits}b}'
'00011010'
```