# Python read a binary file and decode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am quite new in python and I need to solve this simple problem. Already there are several similar questions but still I cannot solve it.
I need to read a binary file, which is composed by several blocks of bytes. For example the header is composed by 6 bytes and I would like to extract those 6 bytes and transform ins sequence of binary characters like 000100110 011001 for example.

```
navatt_dir='C:/PROCESSING/navatt_read/'
navatt_filename='OSPS_FRMT_NAVATT____20130621T100954_00296_caseB.bin'
navatt_path=navatt_dir+navatt_filename

navatt_file=open(navatt_path, 'rb')
header=list(navatt_file.read(6))
print header
```

As result of the list i have the following

```
%run C:/PROCESSING/navatt_read/navat_read.py
['\t', 'i', '\xc0', '\x00', '\x00', 't']
```

which is not what i want.
I would like also to read a particular value in the binary file knowing the position and the length, without reading all the file. IS it possible
thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: To convert bytes to binary strings ("0110101001" etc) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python

Comment: Thanks but maybe I posted the wrong example. Now with seek() I can move and if  ido gps_time = navatt_file.read(1) without creatign a list in the screen appears >, which is correct. So i think it is a porblem to convert an ascii to a binary or integer. How can i do it

Answer (score 2):

### ByteArray

A [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#bytearray) is a mutable sequence of bytes (Integers where 0 ≤ x ≤ 255). You can construct a bytearray from a string (If it is not a byte-string, you will have to provide encoding), an iterable of byte-sized integers, or an object with a buffer interface. You can of course just build it manually as well.

An example using a byte-string:

```
string = b'DFH'
b = bytearray(string)

# Print it as a string
print b

# Prints the individual bytes, showing you that it's just a list of ints
print [i for i in b]

# Lets add one to the D
b[0] += 1

# And print the string again to see the result!
print b
```

The result:

```
DFH
[68, 70, 72]
EFH
```

This is the type you want if you want raw byte manipulation. If what you want is to read 4 bytes as a 32bit int, one would use the struct module, with the unpack method, but I usually just shift them together myself from a bytearray.

### Printing the header in binary

What you seem to want is to take the string you have, convert it to a bytearray, and print them as a string in base 2/binary.

So here is a short example for how to write the header out (I read random data from a file named "dump"):

```
with open('dump', 'rb') as f:
    header = f.read(6)

b = bytearray(header)

print ' '.join([bin(i)[2:].zfill(8) for i in b])
```

After converting it to a bytearray, I call bin() on every single one, which gives back a string with the binary representation we need, in the format of "0b1010". I don't want the "0b", so I slice it off with [2:]. Then, I use the string method zfill, which allows me to have the required amount of 0's prepended for the string to be 8 long (which is the amount of bits we need), as bin will not show any unneeded zeroes.

If you're new to the language, the last line might look quite mean. It uses list comprehension to make a list of all the binary strings we want to print, and then join them into the final string with spaces between the elements.

A less pythonic/convoluted variant of the last line would be:

```
result = []
for byte in b:
    string = bin(i)[2:] # Make a binary string and slice the first two bytes
    result.append(string.zfill(8)) # Append a 0-padded version to the results list

# Join the array to a space separated string and print it!
print ' '.join(result)
```

I hope this helps!