# Reading from a binary file and decoding using Python

Tags: python-3.x, struct, encoding, file-io, binary

I have a binary file from a mainframe which I'm trying to read using Python and produce a human readable text file. I'm still gathering more information about the file. What I do know is that the file serves as input to COBOL programs.
I try to read the file into python like this:

```
with open('P_MF.DAT', mode='rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read(500)
```

When I `print(file_content)` I get something like:

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@@@@@@@@\x00\x00@@@\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf0@@@@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@@@\x00\x00\x00\x00@@@@@@\xf0\xf0\xf0\xf4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00Q\x08c\x18\x1f\xc5@@@\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x11?\x00\x00\x10\x02F\x17o@@\xd5@\xc9\xd5\xc7\xd3\xc9\xe2@\xd4\xc1\xd9\xe8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Then I tried this using the codecs module which also gives me gibberish:

```
import codecs
file_content1 = codecs.decode(file_content, 'cp500')
```

But I can see a few readable characters in the output when I `print(file_content1)`:

'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00        \x00\x00   000000000000000    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00   \x00\x00\x00\x00      0004\x00\x00\x00\x00\x97\x02\x00\x00é\x97Ä\x18\x1fE   \x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x11\x1a\x00\x00\x10\x02ã\x87?  N INGLIS MARY                             \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

I've been googling around for a couple of days. Tried a number of things like this - [Python read a binary file and decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016425/python-read-a-binary-file-and-decode)
I feel like I'm getting nowhere with this problem. I also plan to ask how this file looks if read in a mainframe. I'd appreciate any info/help/advice at this point.
​

Comment: Decoding implies text.  Not all binary data is text data.  You have a mix of binary and text data and must know the structure of the data and only decode the text portions.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen. That makes a lot of sense. Will get the structure of the data and try it.