# Python Bits and bytes

Tags: python, bit

I was wondering how i could extract the last 2 bits of a byte. I receive the bytes when reading in from a file.

`byte = b'\xfe'
 bits = bin(byte)`

```
output: 0b00110001
```

I want to know how i can 7th and 8th bit from that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to bits in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python)

Comment: I don't think that code would work in either Python 2 or Python 3, and even if it did, that's not the binary associated with `0xFE`.  Please try to copy and paste actual transcripts where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always the old fashioned trick of masking:

```
>>> bits = bin(byte[0] & 0x03)
>>> bits
'0b10'
```