# Searching a more elegant way for converting a byte to a list of bits

Tags: python, list, function, byte, bit

I'm currently using this little function for converting a byte to a list of integer bits, because I need to iterate over the single bits of a byte.

```
def byteToBitList(byte):
    return [int(bit) for bit in "{0:08b}".format(byte)]
```

but I don't think it's very elegant. Is there a better way to do this? Possibly without using strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always benefit from using [bitwise operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), which works with a standard integer object. Simply shift your number one bit at time and collect the right-most bit value. For instance:

```
>>> byte = 0xFC
>>> list_size = 8
>>> [(byte >> i) & 1 for i in range(list_size)][::-1] # reverse this array, since left-most bits are evaluated first.
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Timing using IPython: `1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 µs per loop`

It's even possible to generate this list without reversing the array:

```
>>> byte = 0xFC
>>> list_size = 8
>>> [(byte & (1 << (list_size - 1 - k))) >> (list_size - 1 - k) for k in range(list_size)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Timing using IPython: `100000 loops, best of 3: 2.3 µs per loop`. Apparently, it's faster to reverse a list than to use two shifts!

Also, [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python) contains a pretty similar question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid string operations, you can use binary operations, namely shifts `<<` and `>>` combined with the logical and `&`.

```
>>> def byteToBitList(byte):
    return [(byte & (1 << k)) >> k for k in range(8)]

>>> byteToBitList(0xfc)
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Notice that your output is reversed: `0xFC` is `0b11111100`. I've written an answer to this question showing how to get the bit list in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following solution which is a bit faster :

```
byte = 0xfc

In [206]: list(map(int, bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8)))
Out[206]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

**Timing**:

```
In [209]: %timeit byteToBitList(byte)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.69 us per loop

In [211]: %timeit list(map(int, bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.27 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `bin()` and a little pruning with `str.zfill()` to convert the integer to it's binary representation:

```
def byteToBitList(byte):
    return [int(bit) for bit in bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8)]
```

This assumes that `byte` is indeed an unsigned integer of value 0-255. Any larger and the resultant list will exceed 8 bits although the result will be correct, just not zero padded.