# recreate the image using the extracted bites and saved in a txt file

Tags: python, image, byte

I'm trying to extract the binary information from an image (like `\ xff`), and save it into a text file. Ultimately, I should also be able to reverse the effect, and generate an image from the text file.

I'm using the code below to try to create the text file; it does not throw an error, but the text generated does not generate an image. [Here is an example of the contents of one of the text files created by this code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nte1-uXqkRWvhs2eYz1E2zyHWWStGCHm/view?usp=sharing)

```
file = open(image, "rb")
data = file.read()
file.close()


file = open(txt file, "w")
file.write(str(data))
file.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried? In what ways did that fail?

Comment: what do you mean of "bites"?

Comment: sorry I forgot file.write(str(data)) instead of file.write(data)

Comment: I mean with bites for example "\ xff"

Comment: @bob bytes? bit is 1/8 byte

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter the program to recreate the images from the bites gives no error but when I open the .jpg file it does not show me any image

Comment: @bob you want to read your image bytes like 01 string and then convert these 01 to their original bytes again ?

Comment: @DRPK I would like to convert an image to bits and save all those bits to a txt file and then use that txt file to create the image

Comment: You cannot convert a bytes object to a str using ```file.write(str(data))```. You have to define an encoding. I do not understand your intention.

Comment: @bob check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should read/write your files on binary mode with "rb" and "wb" attributes on open() function:

**Try this:**

```
with open(image1, "rb") as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()

with open(image2, "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(data)
```

But if you want to convert your target file bytes to bits (01) and save them and reverse this job again you can simply use numpy package:

**Try This:**

```
import numpy as np

Bytes = np.fromfile("image1.png", dtype="uint8")
Bits = np.unpackbits(Bytes)


with open("bits.txt", "w") as export_bits:
    export_bits.write("".join(list(map(str, Bits))))

with open("bits.txt", "r") as load_bits:
    string_bits_data = list(map(int, load_bits.read()))


save_new_image = np.packbits(string_bits_data).astype('int8').tofile("image2.png")
print("Done")
```

Credits to mikhail-v (UID: 4157407) from: [Convert bytes to bits in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python).